# How to generate a random mathematical operator

Tags: c, math, random

I have an assignment that requires me to make a quiz which generates random math questions. I'm fine with everything but i'm struggling to find a way to randomly choose between the mathematical operators "+" and "-".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    int choice = 0;
    int lives = 0;
    int question = 1;
    int a;
    int b;
    int answer = 0;
    int ans = 0;
    int correct = 0;
    printf("\n Welcome to Maths Tester Pro.");
    printf("\n Please Select a difficulty:");
    printf("\n 1) Easy");
    printf("\n 2) Medium");
    printf("\n 3) Hard \n");
    scanf("%d%*c",&choice);
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1:
        printf("You have selected Easy mode!");
        lives = lives+3;
        while ((lives !=0)&&(question !=6)){
            if(question !=5){
                                    //Ask Question
                printf("\nQuestion %d of 5.  You have %d lives remaining", question, lives);
                srand(time(NULL));
                a = (rand() % (10 - 1 + 1)) + 1;    //make the sign random
                b = (rand() % (10 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
                printf("\n%d + %d = ",a ,b);
                scanf("%d", &answer);
                ans = a+b;
                                    //If answer is correct
                if((a+b) == answer){
                    printf("Correct!\n");
                    correct = correct + 1;
                }
                                    //If answer is incorrect
                else{
                    printf("Incorrect!  The correct answer was %d\n",ans);
                    lives=lives-1;
                }
                question = question + 1;
            }
```

In my code I have it written as ans=a+b but I want it to be able to randomly pick either "+" or "-".

Comment: You need to remember the chosen operator somehow and run a different calculation based on that. Probbaly the simplest way to do this is to have an `enum { OPERATION_ADD, OPERATION_SUBTRACT } operation;` and `switch` on that.

Comment: Unrelated: not sure why you tagged this as C++, I don't see a single C++ feature being used.

Comment: to choose a random operator, you can create a random number between 0 and 2, then check if this number is above or below 1

Comment: Aside: move `srand(time(NULL));` to the beginning of `main()` and call *once only*.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to go would be to change the sign of `b`. To do so, simply multiply it by either `1` (keeps positive sign) or `-1` (makes it a negative):

```
b = b * ((rand() - (RAND_MAX / 2)) > 0 ? 1 : -1);
```

Upon execution, you will randomly get `a + b` or `a + (-b)`.

Example print of the resulting operator:

```c
printf("%d%s%d = %d\n", a, (b > 0 ? "+" : ""), b, a + b);
```

Note: as pointed in earlier comments, you may also want to randomize the seed in order to prevent you application to keep providing the "same" random numbers with:

```
/* Randomize seed (needed once). */
srand(time(NULL));

/* Then make your calls to `rand()`. */
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I offer this as an example of how to cleanly generate and print the sort of problems that you seem to want.

This produces 20 'sum' and/or 'difference' equations. You can simply suppress printing the total in order to pose the question to the user.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {

    srand( time( NULL ) );

    for( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ ) {
        int a = (rand() % 10) + 1; // 1 <= a <= 10
        int b = (rand() % 20) - 9; // -9 <= b <= 10

        printf( "%d %c %d = %d\n", a, "+-"[b<0], abs( b ), a+b );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
1 + 3 = 4
1 - 6 = -5
4 + 10 = 14
8 + 2 = 10
10 + 0 = 10
4 + 4 = 8
8 + 10 = 18
8 + 9 = 17
8 - 2 = 6
8 - 4 = 4
2 + 1 = 3
8 - 5 = 3
2 - 6 = -4
4 + 9 = 13
6 + 6 = 12
5 + 0 = 5
3 + 4 = 7
1 + 0 = 1
9 - 5 = 4
8 + 8 = 16
```

The keen eyed reader will notice that even "10 + 0" is a reasonable problem. Zero is the identity operator(?) for addition (like 1 being the identity operator(?) for multiplication.)

You're free to adjust the ranges of the terms to suit your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rand() function, which is defined in stdlib. And if you want your program to give you different random numbers every time you run it, you need to put srand(time(NULL)) at the beginning, but for the time function, you need to include time.h library